# how to split the array in to two equal parts using php

Tags: php, arrays, slice

how to split an array in to two equal parts using array_slice() in PHP ?

### This is my requirement:

First array contains:  0-1200

Second array contains: 1200-end

Answer (score 13):

From [the documentation for array_slice](https://www.php.net/array_slice), all you have to do is give `array_slice` an offset and a length.

In your case:

```
$firsthalf = array_slice($original, 0, 1200);
$secondhalf = array_slice($original, 1200);
```

In other words, this code is telling `array_slice`:

```
take the first 1200 records;
then, take all the records starting at index 1200;
```

Since index 1200 is item 1201, this should be what you need.

Answer (score 13):

```
$quantity = count($original_collection);

$collection1 = array_slice($original_collection, 0, intval($quantity / 2), true);
$collection2 = array_diff_key($original_collection, $collection1);
```

Comment: I know he specified the numbers, but this option is the better one, as it actually divides any range into 2, not just the 2400 from the question owner. This answers the title of this question.

Comment: So what's the advantage of using both `array_slice` and `array_diff_key` instead of just using `array_splice` once?

Answer (score 7):

```
$array1 = array_slice($array, 0, 1199);
$array2 = array_slice($array, 1200);
```

Answer (score 7):

I think [`array_chunk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) would be easier, especially as you don't need to know how many elements are in the array.

```
array array_chunk ( array $input , int $size [, bool $preserve_keys = false ] )

<?php
$input_array = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
$size = ceil(count($input_array)/2));
print_r(array_chunk($input_array, $size));
print_r(array_chunk($input_array, $size, true));
?>
```

Comment: You have the right idea, but this would chunk the array into many arrays of length 2, not split the array in half. Instead, change the $size to half the array length (using `floor(count($input)/2)`) so that the result would be two arrays containing half the records.

Comment: This is good idea, but will not work in case when size of array will be even number. It will chunk array into 3 parts: first two array will be equal size and last will be array with single element.

Answer (score 5):

```
$array1 = array_slice($input, 0, 1200);
$array2 = array_slice($input, 1200);
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be 0-1201 and 1201?

Comment: @deceze @webarto I don't think so.  I've updated my answer to what I think it should be.  First, `take 1200 records`, then `start at record 1200` which is really record 1201.

Comment: @rock The OP wants "record 0 - 1200" (which is 1201 records) and "record 1200 - end" (which would be starting at offset 1201)... I think the OP is off on that specification though, so no worries. ;-)

Comment: @deceze, something like that :)

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$array1; // your original array with all records
$array2 = array_splice($array1, ceil(count($array1)/2));

// or per your requirement of 1200 in the first array:
$array2 = array_splice($array1, 1200);
```

This just pops off the second half of elements from your original array and puts them in the second array. Not sure what the advantage of using `array_slice` twice like the other answers mention, unless you want 2 new arrays and don't want any elements removed from the original array.