# How to get the middle number of a query in Eloquent Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-blade

I want to get the ID of the number of the middle of a consult in Laravel.

Example: I´m making  a query in Laravel, and it gives me 10 elements, but I want to know which is the element of the middle.

```
$usuario = Auth::user();

    $mensajes = Message::all()->where('asunto', 0);
    $totalResenas = Message::all();

    $totalComentarios = count($mensajes);
    $mitadComentarios = round($totalComentarios/2);
    $mitadComentarios = trim($mitadComentarios);


    $primerosComentarios = $mensajes[$mitadComentarios];
```

The problem is that the result of the last gives me the position of total of elements, and not of the query elements.

[image: The result of the query]

In this case, I want to obtain the element of the middle, the position 5 that has the Id 7.

The view:

```
<!--Primera fila de las reseñas-->
            @foreach($mensajes as $mensaje)
                <!--Si es reseña aqui se mostrará-->
                @if($mensaje->asunto = true)

                        @if($mensaje->id <= $primerosComentarios)
                            <p>{{ $mensaje->id }}</p>
                            <div class="service mb-0">
                                <div class="service__icon"><i class="pe-7s-user"></i></div>

                                <!--Calificacion en estrellitas-->

                                <!--Sacamos el valor de la calificacion-->
                            @php
                                $calificacion = $mensaje->calificacion;
                            @endphp
                            <!--END Sacamos el valor de la calificacion-->

                                <!--Imprimimos las estrellitas-->
                                @for($i = 1; $i <= $calificacion; $i++)
                                    <label class="" style="color: orange" for="radio1">★</label>
                            @endfor
                            <!--END Imprimimos las estrellitas-->

                                <!--END Calificacion en estrellitas-->

                                <h3 style="color:lightseagreen;" class="service__title">{{ $mensaje->name }}</h3>
                                <p class="service__text">{{ $mensaje->mensaje }}</p>
                            </div>
                        @endif

                @endif
                <!--END Si es reseña aqui se mostrará-->

            @endforeach
```

Printing the second half of the query

```
@foreach($mensajes as $mensaje)
                <!--Si es reseña aqui se mostrará-->
                @if($mensaje->asunto = true)

                    @if($mensaje->id > $primerosComentarios && $mensaje->id <= count($totalResenas))
                        <div class="service mb-0">
                            <div class="service__icon"><i class="pe-7s-user"></i></div>

                            <!--Calificacion en estrellitas-->

                            <!--Sacamos el valor de la calificacion-->
                        @php
                            $calificacion = $mensaje->calificacion;
                        @endphp
                        <!--END Sacamos el valor de la calificacion-->

                            <!--Imprimimos las estrellitas-->
                            @for($i = 1; $i <= $calificacion; $i++)
                                <label class="" style="color: orange" for="radio1">★</label>
                        @endfor
                        <!--END Imprimimos las estrellitas-->

                            <!--END Calificacion en estrellitas-->
                            <h3 style="color:lightseagreen;" class="service__title">{{ $mensaje->name }}</h3>
                            <p class="service__text">{{ $mensaje->mensaje }}</p>
                        </div>
                    @endif

                @endif
                <!--END Si es reseña aqui se mostrará-->

            @endforeach
```

Comment: Please replace this line `$mensajes = Message::all()->where('asunto', 0);` with this `$mensajes = Message::where('asunto', 0)->get();` and check the output.

Comment: Check [`array_slice`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) function, but maybe more applicable for your case here would be [`array_chunk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5561952/how-to-split-the-array-in-to-two-equal-parts-using-php) answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, you can use laravel's helper for collection:

```
$chunks = $mensajes->chunk($mitadComentarios);
```

so this way you would get two smaller collections divided to half by element count.

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-chunk).

Answer (score 2):

Try this lines of code. Hope this might help you.

```
$mensajes = Message::where('asunto', 0)->get();

$totalComentarios = count($mensajes);
$mitadComentarios = floor($totalComentarios/2);

$primerosComentarios = $mensajes[$mitadComentarios];
```